# Как принять JSON файл через PHP?

Tags: php

Сервис присылает JSON через webhook. Нужно что бы каждый раз, когда с сервиса приходит webhook на мой сервер, запускался php скрипт, который данный JSON записывал, например в файл txt. Как такое можно осуществить? 
Я не понимаю куда мне настраивать отправку webhook'а, на 80 порт, на котором запущен PHP или прямо прописывать путь до файла скрипта? Подскажите пожалуйста какой вариант будет правильным. Код я напишу сам, мне интересно как реализовать данную задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В хуке, который будет присылать json данные, нужно указать адрес скрипта, который будет выполнять обработку действия (сохранять в txt-файл).

Адрес скрипта - это url страницы, скажем http://mysite.ru:8080/folder/save_json.php

Некоторые части url можно опускать. Например, если у вас веб-сервер на 80 порту, то можете указать url просто как http://mysite.ru/folder/save_json.php

PS Хорошо сформулированный вопрос - половина ответа. 
Посмотрите на заголовок своего вопроса, он по факту не очень хорошо отражает ваш вопрос. В заголовке есть слово "файл", оно там не нужно: не фигурирует ни в вашем вопросе, ни в ответе. 
У вас вопрос (так, как его прочитал я и на что отвечал я) это "Как указать адрес PHP-страницы, обрабатывающей json-запрос".

Некоторые формулировки вопроса некорректны. PHP не может быть запущен на 80 порту, на 80 порту может быть запущен веб-сервер (iis, apache, nginx etc), который обрабатывает запросы приходящие по протоколу http(s). И уже веб-сервер может для некоторых запросов (например, для тех запросов, где запрос заканчивается на .php или на .php5) вызвать PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Честно не понял что вы подразумеваете под этим "прямо прописывать путь до файла скрипта?".

Если сервис с которого приходит webhook  обладает возможностью записывать в файл ,
то тогда не надо лишний раз дёргать ваш сервер со скриптом.Если нет то тут уже без вариантов. PHP code file_put_content json stroku.Единственное что вы должны проверять json на валидность.json это текстовый формат